# Angular 5 Material How to add Dropdowns to a Multi-level Carousel style SideNav?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5, components

[image]
Hello World, I have a sidenav that basically works with tabs, just the effect I wanted to achieve in transition. But now I would like to add that by clicking on "Option 1, Option 2 or Option 3" make this transition from the tab, but the two options that would come out now, are dropdowns with 5 options and 2 options (When opening the dropdown) But I can not find the way to achieve it. Does anyone have any idea where to start or something like that?

Here is my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5xefi-xbxn4i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 19.12.2018**

See latest stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5xefi-urizmb?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html) for a solution that mimics the desired behaviour like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/9aaaf58ee78448052d12ce5ce8fcb221.gif).

**18.12.2018**

I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve exactly, but here is a quick and dirty [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5xefi-f7lqb8?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.html) I have put together. Obviously you would have to style the dropdowns/options a bit to make it look more natural and in line with your other styles.

Changes in **`tab-group-basic-example.ts`**

```
{
  id: 2, // 1st level
  options: [
    { 
      option: 'Dropdown with 5 options', 
      route: '/Submenu1', 
      options: [
        { label: "Option 1", route: "/Submenu1" },
        { label: "Option 2", route: "/Submenu2" },
        { label: "Option 3", route: "/Submenu3" },
        { label: "Option 4", route: "/Submenu4" },
        { label: "Option 5", route: "/Submenu5" },
      ]        
    },
    // { option: 'TestJustIgnore', route: '/Submenu2' },
    // { option: 'TestJustIgnore', route: '/Submenu3' },
    { 
      option: 'Dropdown with 2 options', 
      route: '/Submenu4', 
      options: [
        { label: "Option 1", route: "/Submenu1" },
        { label: "Option 2", route: "/Submenu2" }
      ]  
    },
    // { option: 'TestJustIgnore', route: '/Submenu5' },
  ]
}
```

I added an `options` property which contains an array of options for your dropdown with a text label to display as an option and the route to which it should navigate. When this property is set, instead of a `mat-list-item` a `mat-select` element will be rendered with the options defined.

Changes in the **`tab-group-basic-example.html`**

```
<a mat-list-item *ngIf="!rootOption.rootTab && !rootOption.options"
                 [routerLink]="rootOption.route" 
                 routerLinkActive="active">
  {{rootOption.option}}
</a>

<mat-select *ngIf="rootOption.options"                        
             placeholder="Select an Option">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of rootOption.options"
              [routerLink]="option.route" 
              [value]="option.label">
    {{option.label}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Basically it checks whether the above mentioned `options` are defined, if yes, then a `mat-select` element will be rendered with the provided options, if not, then a normal `mat-list-item` will be rendered as normal.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the response, I appreciate it very much.

It's almost what I was looking to do, and that I did, but what I can not do is see it in the same sidebar, not as a separate menu. What I want is for the dropdown to go down in the same sidebar, as in this example:
[link](https://i.gyazo.com/9aaaf58ee78448052d12ce5ce8fcb221.gif)

Comment: I still can not find a solution, I've tried several things that I found online and nothing that works. I'll keep trying, if anyone has any idea how I could do it, let me know.

Comment: What if you try to build it with a `mat-accordion` and `mat-expansion-panel` like [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5xefi-kcwkxa?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.html)? Would obviously need to style it but the behaviour is similar to the example like you posted.

Comment: Added some minimal styles so it blends into the menu a bit better [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5xefi-a2zgpw?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.html)

Comment: Omg, thanks!  It's perfect for me, just what I needed. My last question: Is it possible to add some icon (for these navigation options) from the Typescript? I usually added the mat icons directly in the HTML, but in this case; Could I do it from the TypeScript? Really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "from the TypeScript"? You want to use a typescript variable to dynamically show an icon for each option?

Comment: They do not have to be dynamic, it is a navigation and I would like to put icons to the texts that will be there, but normally I did it from the html component, I do not know how to do it from the component.ts. Another thing that is not clear to me is how to change the name of the drop-down (The father, not the ones that come out when clicking). I refer to the ones called Options, here I leave you an image:

Comment: Oh I see, okay here is an updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5xefi-7fy2fg?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.html). You can set the icons via the `icon` property in the options array in your component (it has to be a valid material icon, see [here](https://material.io/tools/icons/) for all of them). I changed it so the title/header is your `option` string that you have defined in your component, the one with "Dropdown with 5/2 options", hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying, the problem is that if I move the Icon property at the beginning, it is still seen at the end of the line (first the text and then the icon) When the idea is that it is at the beginning

Comment: So you want the icon to the left of the text? Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5xefi-urizmb?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html)

Comment: Exactly! with a float left is fixed, but the problem is that the icons only serve for the labels (In the dropdown) but not in the other elements of the navigation (As for example Static 1, Static 2, Static 3, etc)

Comment: Add an icon property for the static objects as well: `{ option: 'Static 1', route: '/StaticItem1', icon: 'filter_1' }` and use it in the template where you display the text: `<a mat-list-item *ngIf="!rootOption.rootTab && !rootOption.options" [routerLink]="rootOption.route" routerLinkActive="active"><mat-icon>{{rootOption.icon}}</mat-icon>{{rootOption.option}}</a>`.

Comment: Thanks, its works for the Static Links, but for the 5th Option (the one called "No Static >") idk where to put the <mat-icon> tag. I already added the icon: 'name' property.

Comment: Add it like this: `<a mat-list-item style="width:100%" *ngIf="rootOption.rootTab" (click)="rootSelected(optionIndex, rootOption.rootTab, rootOption)"><mat-icon>{{rootOption.icon}}</mat-icon>{{rootOption.option}}<div><mat-icon style="padding-left:20%;vertical-align: middle;">chevron_right</mat-icon></div></a>`

Comment: Im trying to import it to my project but crash everything... Not errors, only visual... Can you help me with that?

Comment: I can give it a shot, sure.What are you struggling with exactly? Also please accept the answer if it solved your problem with the dropdown menu. I edited the answer with the final stackblitz/GIF.

Comment: Done.
I uploaded the code to jsfiddle so you can visualize it (it will not render the result).

My code: (the javascript part is the app-header.component.ts)
http://jsfiddle.net/f8ru3m40/1/

Result:
https://i.gyazo.com/978d03222e40116a5bb92396a9d89327.gif

-----


Now what I did was create a new component with the stackblitz code, and I tried to insert it into my code with the selector. http://jsfiddle.net/m14h37au/
Result: https://i.gyazo.com/d30098f7900d227ae918cd6c703c7e95.gif

As you see, now everything is togled (Including content) also the sidenav doesnt look ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185469/discussion-between-s-a-and-fabian-kung).

Comment: hi @Fabian link is no longer available.. is there a updated link I can refer to? Appreciate it thanks!